# Using VLOOKUP data to feed into a formula

Tags: excel, vlookup

In my chart, I have a VLOOKUP formula in COLUMN B and COLUMN D to populate the *brand* and *room count*. These are reference points for the the *returned number* formula in COLUMN E. Since COLUMN B and COLUMN D are using VLOOKUP, it doesn't allow the formula in column E to work unless manually entered.  Is there a way around this?

Here's the formula for COLUMN B:
=VLOOKUP($A2,'SS File 2019Feb13'!$C$1:$DH$4095,3,0)

Here's the formula for COLUMN D:
=VLOOKUP($A2,'SS File 2019Feb13'!$C$1:$DH$4095,4,0)

Here's the formula for COLUMN E:
`=INDEX(AT:AV,MATCH(D2,AK:AK,1)+0,IF(B2="SB",1,IF(B2="CW",2,3)))`

[image: Explanation snag]

[image: Numbers Chart]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't think I understand what you're asking. Can you explain this a bit more " it doesn't allow the formula in column E to work unless manually entered" ?

Comment: What is the Vlookup formula?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to exactly figure out what is going wrong, given that your example does not constitute a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (minimum working example), but I suspect that the mistake might have to do with the dataformat that the vlookup formula returns. If the `vlookup` formula in column D returns a `test/sting` (i.e. "180"), rather than 180 formatted as a number, it might cause trouble in your index match formula as that requires numbers.

You could try:

```
    =INDEX(AT:AV,MATCH(VALUE(D2),AK:AK,1)+0,IF(B2="SB",1,IF(B2="CW",2,3)))
```

which will try to convert the returned value in D2 into a number (if that is possible). Column B, IMHO, is less likely to be the problem, given that is already a string and gets compared to strings.